# create-react-app not creating certain folders

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am having trouble with creating a react app (windows)

NPM Version: 6.14.11

Node version: 14.15.4

Whenever I run `npx create-react-app my-app` I am missing the folders that are usually created. I have my node_modules folder and my package and package-lock JSON files, but I am missing everything else (missing src, public, etc).

When I try to run `npm start`, the script isn't found.

I have already read the Getting Started guide where it says to try `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and I have already updated npm and node. I still cannot get these folders to populate. Any ideas?

Comment: Try 1. Using administrator rights when using the cmd, 2. Use Yarn package manager instead when using npx create-react-app 3. [Set up a react project from scratch using Webpack, Babel, React and React-Router-Dom](http://webpack.js.org)

Comment: Hey @c_the_b, I know you use `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` but may try using this command `npm rm -g create-react-app` then installing it again

Comment: Do you get a error of some kind?

Comment: HenryLy, I tried this and same result.

@PalPalash I get the error "missing script: start" which initially makes sense because the package.json file that gets created does not contain a Scripts section, but even after copying the code from a previous app I made, I get the same result. I also tried copying the entire package.json file itself from the working app into this one and I get the same result.

Comment: @c_the_b try installing it by ``npm i -g create-react-app`` and running ``create-react-app <yourProjectname>``